# how to i can add custom global close button in notistack

Tags: reactjs, notistack

I want to add a custom close button in notistack for all snackbars in my project

I just find below way :

```
enqueueSnackbar('I use snackbars responsibly', {
            variant: 'default',
            action: (key) => (
                <Fragment>
                    <Button
                        size='small'
                        onClick={() => alert(`Clicked on action of snackbar with id: ${key}`)}
                    >
                        Detail
                    </Button>
                    <Button size='small' onClick={() => closeSnackbar(key)}>
                        Dismiss
                    </Button>
                </Fragment>
            )
        });
```

but this way just working for one of snackbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this way

> _app.js  file

```
import { SnackbarProvider, useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

function SnackbarCloseButton({ snackbarKey }) {
  const { closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  return (
    <IconButton onClick={() => closeSnackbar(snackbarKey)}>
      <IconClose />
    </IconButton>
  );
}

<SnackbarProvider action={snackbarKey => <SnackbarCloseButton snackbarKey={snackbarKey} />}>
  ...
</SnackbarProvider>
```